# com_ajax get articles from category joomla

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I am using `com_ajax` to fetch articles from a category,
I have tried to call

`index.php?option=com_ajax&format=json&module=mod_articles_category&id=113`

But it returns the following results,

```
{"success":false,"message":"Module mod_mod_articles_category is not 
published, you do not have access to it, or it's not assigned to the 
current menu item.","messages":null,"data":null}
```

Is it possible to get the data using com_ajax?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just need to pass the module without the 'mod_' prefix.

According to the [documentaion](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface) this should work:

index.php?option=com_ajax&format=json&module=articles_category&id=113

I guess it adds the prefix for you so you end up with mod_mod_

Also, you'll need to ensure that the module is published to the menu item and that you have permissions to access the module etc

So it should be possible to get data using com_ajax as you are trying to do.